# Getting array from text

Tags: javascript, arrays, filereader

I have been experimenting with this code http://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2012/11/20/javascript-csv/  to get data from a text file. (Working demo here: http://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/html-fileapi/).

It works well for reading files, but I am stumped about how to get the data into an array. It seems as though it is reading everything into the "lines" array, but I can't work out how to use it.

I tried modifying it like this:

```
function processData(csv) {
var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var lines = [];
var myArray = [];                      
while (allTextLines.length) {
lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));
myArray.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));   //put data into myArray
}

function myFunction() {                          //display myArray in "demo"
var index;
for (index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++) {
    text += myArray[index];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

but that didn't work. I know I am missing something simple here, but this has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you modify the array twice:

```
lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));     // shift modifies the array
myArray.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));   //gets the shifted array
```

You might want to try putting this in temp variable:

```
var line = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
lines.push(line);
myArray.push(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
csv.split(/\r\n|\n|,/).map(function(value, index) {
  demo.innerHTML += "\n" + value.trim()
});
```

```js
var csv = 'Year,Make,Model,Description,Price'
+ '1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00'
+ '1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00'
+ '1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00'
+ '1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!'
+ 'air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00',

    demo = document.getElementById("demo");

csv.split(/\r\n|\n|,/).map(function(value, index) {
  demo.innerHTML += "\n" + value.trim()
})
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```